# Get anchor inside td

Tags: javascript

I use only JavaScript.

I have the following code inside a function:

```
  siblings=getSiblings(obj);

        for(var i=0;i<siblings.length;i++)
        {
            if(siblings[i].getAttribute('f')=='ytw')
            {
                ytw=siblings[i].innerHTML;
                alert(ytw);
            }
            else if(siblings[i].getAttribute('f')=='ol')
            {
                orderId=siblings[i].innerHTML
                alert(orderId);
            }
        }
```

`siblings[i].innerHTML` returns either an input tag with some VALUE or an anchor tag with some VALUE.

I want to get this value in either case.

Comment: anchor tags don't have a "value" attribute.  What are you trying to get from the anchor?

Comment: @Joseph Well, anchor tags *could* have a value attribute. They just don't, generally.

Comment: the anchor is an order number i want that...actually I have a td which has an anchor and that anchor has a text  I need that text

Comment: @abbas: Instead of using an `innerHTML` string, you should target the specific element you want and get the property or attribute value. To know how best to do that, we'd need to see what your HTML markup looks like.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc  good point. :P  I should clarify:  w3c standard anchor tags do not have a "value" attribute.

Comment: o have added the html in a commnet plz help out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'getAttribute' function to get `VALUE` or `HREF`:

```
 // for input
siblings[i].getAttribute('value'); // or: siblings[i].value
```

And

```
 // for link
siblings[i].getAttribute('href');
```

Or any other attribute:

```
getAttribute('ATTRIBUTE NAME HERE')
```

---

If you want to get `value` in case of input field and text in case of link, you can put up this condition:

```
if (siblings[i].type == 'input') {
   // input box
   var value = siblings[i].value;
   // or: var value = siblings[i].getAttribute('value');
}
else {
   // link
   var value = siblings[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: I think the attribute OP is targeting exists on a descendant element of `siblings[i]`. Or maybe not.

Comment: I have a textbox and i get its siblings ....each sibling is inside a TD and that td has either a text box or an anchor tag....i want the value inside the texbox and the text of the anchor tag

Comment: HTML is a s follows
         <td noWrap="nowrap" f="ol">
         <a class="" href="" value"14"/>
Text - 177035

<input  runat="server" value="353.844"/>

Comment: sorry...the input is also enclosed in a td

Comment: @sarfraz this is not working...for input it is null and for anchor it gives the html for the anchor tag

Comment: innerText worked fine but value is not working..it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
  // for the <a> element
siblings[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('value');

  // for the <input> element
siblings[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].getAttribute('value');
```